# android postgresql database connection error

Tags: java, android, database, postgresql, logcat

i try to connect my android app with my postgresql Databse but it doesn't get a connection the dr iver is running but the connection is not working.

Here is the java code:

```
private void initDatabase() {

    try {

        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        return;

    }

    Connection connection = null;
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://10.0.2.2/Seminarkurs";

    try {

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url , "postgres", "postgres");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        connection.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Failed! Check output console", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    }

}
```

and here is the logcat:

```
01-16 14:40:17.192    8044-8053/com.example.damian.schulkalender E/System﹕ Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
01-16 14:40:17.192    8044-8053/com.example.damian.schulkalender E/System﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.close(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:677)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.finalize(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:1036)
            at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:187)
            at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that this isn't what you want to hear, but it's really not a reasonable thing to do to try to connect directly to a server-side database from a mobile device. I see this question here several times a week, and I'm really not sure why.

The preferred way to do this is to create a server-side application that provides data to your mobile app via an HTTP connection (e.g. a REST Api).

That said, it looks like your attempt to create the connection is failing.
You may get more info by replacing your `e.printStackTrace()` in your exception handler to the use of the Android logger, so that you can see the error in logcat.

Comment: Yea i know that a rest server or a webserver in general is better in many aspects but I don't got any clue how to write one and I don't have that  much time left so I thougt that a direct connection is the easiest and fastest way to get a DB connection working. thanks for your answer